# Complex SQL Counting Query

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a Facility Booking System and I would like to create a CSV format report.
**1. I want to count total booking records**
**2. I want to count how many user booked our facilities, based on that timeslot**
**3. I want to combine two queries into one as I need to put the result into the CSV**

And here is the table structure:

```
fbid | memberid | fbdate     | fbtimeslot | fname    | fposition | fattendance
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    | C00001   | 2014-12-12 | 1          | computer | 1         | 1
2    | C00002   | 2014-12-12 | 1          | computer | 4         | 3
3    | C00003   | 2014-12-12 | 1          | computer | 6         | 1
4    | C00002   | 2014-12-12 | 1          | computer | 8         | 3
5    | C00004   | 2014-12-12 | 1          | computer | 4         | 0
6    | C00002   | 2014-12-12 | 1          | computer | 24        | 1
7    | C00001   | 2014-12-12 | 2          | computer | 1         | 0
8    | C00002   | 2014-12-12 | 3          | computer | 1         | 0
```

For task 1, I have found the solution:
*(fattendance = 3 means the position has changed and I have to keep record but the CSV report doesn't this)*

```
SELECT fbtimeslot, COUNT(*) FROM facilitybooking WHERE fname='computer' AND fattendance<>3 GROUP BY fbtimeslot
```

But for 2 and 3, I tried more than 20 different statements but I still couldn't get the result.
Well, hard tasks though.
I will be very appreciated if you can help me to solve this.

Extras: SQLFiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4800b8/3

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT memberid) doesn't suit your needs? SELECT fbtimeslot, COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT memberid) FROM facilitybooking WHERE fname='computer' AND fattendance<>3 GROUP BY fbtimeslot

Comment: Oh my gosh, can't believe as simple as this. I must got something wrong today. Thanks very much. You're right!